# about php , interactive and dynamic application like ecommerce applications

Tags: php

I am working on a interactive and dynamic php application which has two numbers of products

I want to make the following.

There is a list of products, each product has two buttons buy now and add to cart. Also a quantity field for each product, when I click on buy now  button of one of the product it redirects me to the cart page where it shows the product name, price, quantity, subtotal and total.

On this page I have one button that is "continue-shopping" if I click on it then it redirects me to previous page, if I click on second product of list then it again redirects me to the cart page where it shows only second product description not one that have been added before

Answer (score 0):

Its better to make use of DRUPAL for your development.